Application causes freeze/slowness after using for some time
We have migrated our app into MAUI.
In Android devices or even in emulator release mode if I use the application for some time it starts getting slow and eventually freezes or crashes. It generally happens when I click on a button, and some operation happens and redirects to another screen.
I tried GC.Collect which prevents application crash but make it app slow.
    private async Task ProcesRecord()
{
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    try
    {
        watch.Start();
        if (_qtyRemain > 0)
        {
            Reset();
            return;
        }
        IsBusy = true;
        var dtSave = new DataTable("item_loc");
        dtSave.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));       

        if (_isInd)
        {
            dtSave.Columns.Add("code", typeof(string));
            
        }

        var dtHold = new List<Test>();
        if (!_isInd)
        {
            foreach (var lvItem in Results)
            {
                if (!(lvItem.qty > 0)) continue;
                var dr = dtSave.NewRow();
                dr["id"] = _itemId; 
                dtSave.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var results = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Id)) ? Results.ToList() : ItemList;
            foreach (var lvItem in results ?? [])
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id) && !(lvItem.qty_assigned > 0)) continue;
                var dr = dtSave.NewRow();
                dr["id"] = lvItem.item_id.Trim();
               
             }
        var dsSave = new DataSet("item_loc");
        dsSave.Tables.Add(dtSave);
        dsSave.AcceptChanges();    
        
        dsSave.Dispose();
        dtSave.Dispose();
        dsSave = null;
        dtSave = null;
        var msg = await new ApiController().UpdateItem(model); 
        if (msg?.ToLowerInvariant() != "true")
        {
            string? errorMesg = msg?.Substring(msg.IndexOf("Message:")).Replace("Message:", "");
            if (errorMesg != null)
                await DisplayAlert("Item", errorMesg.Trim(), "Ok");
        }
        else
        {

            switch (_itemType)
            {
                case Type.Item:
                    {
                        var frm = new ItemTabbedPage(_itemType);
                        await GoTo(frm);
                        break;
                    }

                case Type.Accepted:
                    {
                        if (_parentForm != null && _parentForm == "Receive")
                        {
                            var frm = new ReceivePage();
                            await GoTo(frm);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var navigation = Application.Current?.MainPage?.Navigation;
                            if (navigation?.NavigationStack[navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2] is AssignPage previousPage)
                            {
                                navigation.RemovePage(previousPage);
                            }

                            var tabbedPage = new CVAwayPage();
                            if (tabbedPage.Children[0] is CVReadyPage cvReadyPage)
                            {
                                if (_sendSeaBack)
                                {
                                    tabbedPage.Children[0] = new CVReadyPage(_itemId);  
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    tabbedPage.Children[0] = new CVReadyPage();
                                }
                            }
                            await Application.Current!.MainPage!.Navigation.PushAsync(tabbedPage);                  
                        }

                        break;
                    }
               
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayErrorAlert(ex.Message);
        ReportError("Items: Failed.", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (watch.IsRunning)
        {
          
            watch.Stop();
            string paramvalue = "Test";
            string count = Results != null ? Results.Count.ToString() : "0";
            int success = await InsertExecutionLogDetails("Items", paramvalue, count, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
           
        }
    }
}

And OnAppearing of the next page where it should redirects having this below code
protected override void OnAppearing()
  {
      try
      {
          base.OnAppearing();
          ViewModel?.OnAppearing();
          SetupListeners();
          GC.Collect();
          GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          ReportError("AssignItemPage.OnAppearing: Failed.", ex);
          DisplayErrorAlert(ex.Message);
      }
  }

Data grid usage in screen
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="7" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0">
     <dg:DataGrid x:Name="Grid" ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" HeightRequest="230">
         <dg:DataGrid.NoDataView>
             <Label Text="No item locations found, please setup new item location(s)." TextColor="Crimson" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
         </dg:DataGrid.NoDataView>
         <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
             <helpers:DataGridColumn Title="Location" Width="100" PropertyName="location_label"/>
             <helpers:DataGridColumn Title="Cur.Qty" Width="80" PropertyName="total_qty" />
             <helpers:DataGridColumn Title="Asnd." Width="80" PropertyName="qty_assigned"/>
             <helpers:DataGridColumn Title="Status" Width="100" PropertyName="inventory_loc_status"/>
             <helpers:DataGridColumn Title="MaxQty" Width="80" PropertyName="item_loc_max_qty" />
             <helpers:DataGridColumn Title="Type" Width="160" PropertyName="location_type"/>
             <helpers:DataGridColumn Title="Size" Width="110" PropertyName="location_size"/>
         </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
     </dg:DataGrid>
 </StackLayout>

DataGrid.xaml file
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
        <Grid x:Name="HeaderView" RowSpacing="0" Padding="0,0,0,0">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <!--Default Header Style-->
                    <Style x:Key="HeaderDefaultStyle" TargetType="Label">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Start"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Start"/>
                        <Setter Property="LineBreakMode" Value="TailTruncation"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Grid">
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{Binding HeaderBackground,Source={x:Reference Self}}"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="ImageStyleBase" TargetType="Image">
                        <Setter Property="Aspect" Value="AspectFill"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="5"/>
                        <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="9"/>
                        <!--<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,4,0"/>-->
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="AscendingIconStyle" TargetType="Image" BasedOn="{StaticResource ImageStyleBase}">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding AscendingIcon, Source={x:Reference Self}}"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="DescendingIconStyle" TargetType="Image" BasedOn="{StaticResource ImageStyleBase}">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding DescendingIcon, Source={x:Reference Self}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </Grid.Resources>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
    <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollView x:Name="Sv" Orientation="Horizontal" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
            <helpers:DataGridListView x:Name="ListView" HeightRequest="190" VerticalOptions="Start"></helpers:DataGridListView>
        </ScrollView>
        <helpers:DataGridVertScrollBar IsVisible="{Binding EnableCustomScroll}" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="End" x:Name="ssv" HeightRequest="190" WidthRequest="10" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="HeightProportional,YProportional,XProportional"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,8,1"></helpers:DataGridVertScrollBar>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
    <ContentView x:Name="NoDataViewElement" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="False"/>
</Grid>

checked in Appcenter also but it does not capture this crash or freeze
Can some help to fix
Thanks

Please provide the relevant code for the event that redirects to another page

You need to profile your app https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Profiling-.NET-MAUI-Apps

Hi @FreakyAli Package 'dotnet-trace 8.0.532401' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project 'AndroidTest'. giving me this error while installing

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1202 Package dotnet-trace 8.0.532401 is not compatible with net8.0-android34.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package dotnet-trace 8.0.532401 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) / any

I don't think this is slowing your app...

I have custom datagrid in xaml if I remove that application works fine. Datagrid might have some issue?

@FreakyAli exactly after certain number of transaction going from one screen to child and get back to parent causing freeze. Child page has custom datagrid control. How to identify what is causing freeze?

Profile your application so you know what is causing this did you see the link i sent here?

@FreakyAli yes I was getting error "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error NU1202 Package dotnet-trace 8.0.532401 is not compatible with net8.0-android34.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package dotnet-trace 8.0.532401 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)" while following the steps

That is all you get?

@FreakyAli unable to install

Can you add the relevant code about datagrid, which could be the cause of this problem

@FreakyAli I am able to get the CPU utilization trace file and gc dump file but that contains so many details how to get the root cause of memory leak?

@ShuowenHe-MSFT updated in code above please check

What version of Android are you running the project on? Does this problem only occur on Android? Have you tried iOS?

@ShuowenHe-MSFT only using Android and version is A12

Did the project work normally before migrating to MAUI?

@ShuowenHe-MSFT very smoothly

Are any third-party APIs used in the project? Can you provide the code for the .csproj file? Or can you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example directly?

@ShuowenHe-MSFT no third part API in my project. I am using handlers so I have read that .net 8 does not calls disconnect handler by own. Any way to call it manually? may be that is the cause of memory leak?

You can refer to this issue(DisconnectHandler is never called), MAUI doesn't call DisconnectHandler automatically. by what way you call it manually? Can you provide the code?
